# Pasting python's tabulate output to Microsoft Office editors

Tags: python, outlook

Quite frequently I need to copy-paste small tables from an SQL editor into Microsoft Office programs (Outlook and OneNote) and I want it to look nice as I paste it. So I wrote a short script taking the data from the clipboard, processing it with Tabulate and returning it to the clipboard.
This works very well when I paste the new table into Notepad++ and other editors. It completely messes up when I paste into Outlook. 
If I paste into Notepad++ and then copy paste from there, everything's fine.
I tried the different table formats, and I tried playing around with Outlook's editor options.

Would really appreciate any insights!

Thanks!

See code:

```
import win32clipboard
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

df = pd.read_clipboard()
head = df.columns.tolist()
val = df.values

table =  tabulate(val,headers=head,tablefmt="grid")

# set clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(str(table))
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```